# file_get_contents dont work?

Tags: php, queue, redis, file-get-contents

Server: PHP 5.3

The line in question:

```
file_get_contents(http://subdomain.domain.com/Api/id);
```

In `http://subdomain.domain.com/Api/id` I have this:

```
$newFeeds = new newsFeeds();
$newFeeds->function($newsFeedParseFile); //insertamos a memcachedb
```

and from here it doesn't work

```
$redis = cacheFactory::get('redis');    
$redis->addTolist("Info_{1_2_FS}", "InfoRedis");
```

I don't get any error, it just doesn't add to queue.

The wear things is when I copy the address http://subdomain.domain.com/Api/id and paste in the address bar I get the response that I want!

Comment: Is the code accurate? I see syntax errors: missing quotes.

Comment: Is that subdomain site served from the same machine as the site running the script doing the file_get_contents. Some hosting providers have firewall setups that prevent a machine from talking to itself via TCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify in your php.ini if "allow_url_fopen" is On, if isn't change it to On.